# function calling issue in python Rock Paper Scissors project

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

im fairly new to programing...
im working on a rock paper scissors game and everything works up until i need to show where player wins, or computer opponent wins, or if there is a tie.  The program just keeps asking for input to choose a weapon.
if anyone can show me why the wining or tie functions arent getting called id be very thankful
heres my code:

```
# Rock Paper Scissors game
import random

# player chooses between Rock Paper or Scissors
def player_move():
    global player_name
    shoot = input('{} Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: '.format(player_name))
    while shoot[0].lower() != 'r' and shoot[0].lower() != 'p' and shoot[0].lower() != 's':
        print('sorry you must only choose r, p, or s')
        shoot = input('Try again: ')
    if shoot[0].lower() == 'r':
        shoot = 'Rock'
    if shoot[0].lower() == 'p':
        shoot = 'Paper'
    if shoot[0].lower() == 's':
        shoot = 'Scissors'
    print('your move <{}>'.format(shoot))
    return shoot

# computer opponent randomly choses between Rock paper or scissors
def opponent_move():
    lst = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
    move = random.choice(lst)
    print('opponent move <{}>'.format(move))
    return move

# compare between player and comp & declare a winner or a tie
# player winning scenarios
def player_win():
    return ((player_move() == 'Scissors' and opponent_move() == 'Paper') or
            (player_move() == 'Paper' and opponent_move() == 'Rock') or
            (player_move() == 'Rock' and opponent_move() == 'Scissors'))

# opponent winning scenarios
def opponent_win():
    return ((opponent_move() == 'Scissors' and player_move() == 'Paper') or
            (opponent_move() == 'Paper' and player_move() == 'Rock') or
            (opponent_move() == 'Rock' and player_move() == 'Scissors'))

# what happens if there's a tie
def tie():
    return player_move() == opponent_move()

### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ### main ##
print('Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors')
player_name = input('Whats your name? ').capitalize()
limit = int(input('{}, until what score would you like to play? '.format(player_name)))
opponent_score = 0
player_score = 0
play = True

while play:
    while limit > player_score and limit > opponent_score:
        print('opponents score ', opponent_score)
        print('{}s score '.format(player_name), player_score)
        player_move()
        opponent_move()
        if player_win():
            print('{} wins!'.format(player_name))
            player_score += 1
        if opponent_win():
            print('opponent wins :( ')
            opponent_score += 1
        if tie():
            print('its a tie...')
    # when score limit is reached
    if player_score == limit:
        print('Congradulatins {} you won!!!'.format(player_name))
        play = False
    if opponent_score == limit:
        print('{}, im sorry you have lost :( '.format(player_name))
        play = False

# ask if player wants to play again
if not play:
    ask = input('play again? y/n ')
    if ask[0].lower() == 'y':
        opponent_score = 0
        player_score = 0
        play = True
    else:
        print('thanks for playing')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each single round, you make multiple calls to `player_move()` and `opponent_move()`. In `player_win()` and `opponent_win()` those should not be called again.

Basically you are asking the player and opponent for their move but when you check for the first possible outcome (scissors vs. paper), you suddenly "forgot" their moves and ask them again. Of course, their choice may now be different each time.

Instead, save the result in your main loop, and pass it as an argument, for example:

```
def player_win(player_choice, opponent_choice):
    return ((player_choice == 'Scissors' and opponent_choice == 'Paper') or
            (player_choice == 'Paper' and opponent_choice == 'Rock') or
            (player_choice == 'Rock' and opponent_choice == 'Scissors'))

def opponent_win(...):
    return ...
```

and in your main program:

```
    player_choice = player_move()
    opponent_choice = opponent_move()
    if player_win(player_choice, opponent_choice):
    ...
```